# Playframework Database unit tests fail in subprojects

Tags: java, unit-testing, ebean, playframework-2.3, subproject

Unit tests in Play subprojects using a database fail due to this Error:

*javax.persistence.PersistenceException: The default EbeanServer has not been defined? This is normally set via the ebean.datasource.default property. Otherwise it should be registered programatically via registerServer()*

It is thrown when doing something like this:

```
MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
entity.save();
```

Also

```
server = Ebean.getServer("default");
```

won't work either -It would cause this error:
*java.lang.RuntimeException: DataSource user is null?*

The only (very ugly) workaround that I have found is to move the Unit Test to the root Play project that hosts the subproject, which contains the model classes (*MyEntity*).

Has anybody an idea how to get the unit test working in the subproject?

Comment: Please keep in mind that unit-testing usually requires abstracting database access behind a repository interface. This allows for easy mocking and unit-testing without a live database or running application. See 'Unit testing models': https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaTest. (This was an answer before, but @user3271386 was right that this is more of a guess/hint about possible architectural problems than an actual solution for sub-projects)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `evolutionplugin=enabled`